Why does an app pauses and looses audio?
This happens to be daily. Listening to Youtube with bluetooth headset, then suddenly w/out any prompt Youtube pauses, and when I press play it continues w/out audio. Closing Youtube and loading it again doesn't help at all; audio is still missing. On the other hand, forcing app to stop via Settings/Apps and re-starting fixes the problem. Until a few ours later, that is.
What could have caused this problem and how to fix it for good?
Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra, Android 14, One UI 6.1, Youtube app 19.31.36
